# How to get back to app if we open aexternal URL link in ios app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Actually I'am Doing a Cordova Project in which I will be opening an external link which contains an image so what's my problem is after seeing that image how can I redirect him back to the app. so that he can browse app.

Any Solution For this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about using [`InAppBrowser`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html)

Comment: I dont know whether its opening in an InAppBrowser or not its showing the image. only on clicking some icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [InAppBrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) for this.  You can override the default link behavior which would take over your entire application's Web view with the content of the link with no way back to the application.  You'd do this something like this (find all links in a div and open them with the InAppBrowser adding a flip animation when transitioning between app and InAppBrowser (this uses JQuery but you get the idea):

```
amendLinks : function (selector) {
    $(selector).find('a').each(
        function() {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            var iabOptions = (device.platform === 'iOS' ? 'location=no,enableViewportScale=yes,transitionstyle=fliphorizontal' : '');

            if (href.indexOf('http') === 0) {
                $(this).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    cordova.InAppBrowser.open(''.concat(this.href), '_blank', iabOptions);
                });
            }
        }
    );      
}
```